# play - add global variable to custom tag

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a string (obtained dynamically through a server side request) that represents HTML. In this HTML, there is a custom play tag. For example:

```
<html><body><div>#{myTag /}</div></body></html>
```

Now, I want to pass a variable to this tag:

```
Template playTemplate = TemplateLoader.loadString(myHtml); // the HTML above
playTemplate.compile();

SomeObject myObject = SomeObject.find("name", "test").first();
Map<String,Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("myObject", myObject);
String result = playTemplate.render(args);
```

And in my custom "myTag.tag", the code looks like this:

```
<p>
    Hello world: ${myObject.name}
</p>
```

But I get an error:

```
Exception raised was NullPointerException : Cannot get property 'name' on null object.
```

The object is not null. When I replace `#{myTag /}` with `${myObject.name}` in the HTML string, everything works fine! How do I pass an object to a custom tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template should be

```
<html><body><div>#{myTag obj: myObject/}</div></body></html>
```

And your tag should be

```
<p>Hello world: ${_obj.name}</p>
```

In essence, you need to explicitly pass render args from template to tag.

the [Rythm template engine](http://playframework.org/modules/rythm) support implicit pass render args to tag however. It brings many other features not found in groovy template. Check the full demo at http://rythmengine.com

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I did indeed look at the Rythm template but neither me or my team has any experience with it. Is it production ready?

Comment: I am using it in several product projects. At least one big project in China use it heavily as far as I know.